# Grouping alternating data

Tags: f#, functional-programming, hashtable, grouping

Given is a text file where keys and values are in alternating order, like so:

```
KeyA
ValueA
KeyB
ValueB
KeyC
ValueC
...
```

I would like to create a dictionary/hashtable from that data. How would I go for that in a functional manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this, although I'm not sure if this is the most "functional" approach:

```
let dic = Dictionary<string,string>()
File.ReadAllLines(@"keyvalue.txt")
|> Seq.pairwise
|> Seq.iteri( fun i (a,b)-> if i % 2 = 0 then dic.Add(a,b))
```

Comment: Its probably a little easier to write `iteri(fun i (a, b) -> ... dict.Add(a, b))` rather than decomposing the tuple with `fst/snd`.

Comment: great idea with `Seq.pairwise`. fyi you don't need to break apart the tuple `x` in the lambda since .NET calls (`dic.Add`) take tuples!: `fun i x-> if i % 2 = 0 then dic.Add x`. And even if that weren't the case, you could use pattern matching to break apart the tuple without `fst` and `snd`: `fun i (a,b)-> if i % 2 = 0 then dic.Add(a,b)`.

Comment: @Juliet - apparently it took me more than 8 minutes to write my comment!

Comment: @Stephen - I didn't know that, thanks! That will help going forward

Comment: The first argument to iteri being a curried function you could also go with: `(fun i -> if i % 2 = 0 then dic.Add else ignore)`

Finally, there's also a dict keyword to create a dictionary from a collection of tuples, but sadly you'd have to filter out the odd-indexed values.

Answer (score 6):

@BrokenGlass was right on the ball recognizing `Seq.pairwise` as the perfect fit for extracting your data. But for a more functional solution use the immutable `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Map` instead of the mutable `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines @"keyvalue.txt"
|> Seq.pairwise
|> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> if i % 2 = 0 then Some(x) else None)
|> Seq.choose id
|> Map.ofSeq
```

And if your data file is huge, consider reading in the values as a stream, for better performance:

```
seq { 
    use sr = System.IO.File.OpenText @"keyvalue.txt"
    while(not sr.EndOfStream) do yield (sr.ReadLine(), sr.ReadLine())
}
|> Map.ofSeq
```

Comment: @Kha - nice, I wasn't aware of `File.ReadLines` -- since it's new to .NET 4.0, I'll go ahead and leave my examples unchanged for those F# programmers targeting .NET 2.0 / 3.5.

Answer (score 5):

I think all the answers posted before give a fine solution. Interestingly, this is not something that could be elegantly solved using F# sequence expressions - you have to use either lists & recursion, some tricky functions (e.g. `pairwise`) or use the `IEnumerator` interface.

I wrote a computation builder that allows you to work with `IEnumerator` (see the [full source code on fssnip.net](http://fssnip.net/37)). Using this computation, you could solve it very nicely:

```
let loadFile path = 
  // Recursive function that generates IEnumerator of key * value pairs
  let rec loop source = iter {
    // Read key & value and continue if both are available
    let! key = source
    let! value = source
    match key, value with
    | Some key, Some value -> 
       // Produce key * value pair and continue looping
       yield key, value
       yield! loop source
    | _ -> () }

  // Create sequence that reads data and convert it to dictionary
  Enumerator.toSeq (fun () ->
    loop (File.ReadAllLines(@"keyvalue.txt").GetEnumerator())) |> dict
```

I find the `iter` computation very nice - there are some cases where you cannot solve problem using F# `seq`. Then you can use recursion and lists - but the same recursion pattern can be also quite neatly written using `iter`.

Answer (score 2):

```
let loadFile path =
    let rec loop acc = function
    | k::v::rest -> loop ((k, v)::acc) rest
    | []         -> dict acc
    | _          -> failwith "odd number of lines"

    path |> System.IO.File.ReadAllLines |> List.ofArray |> loop []
```

Answer (score 0):

Break it down in to a list of strings, use [List.choose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353456.aspx#Y500) or [Seq.choose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340250.aspx) to split it in to odd/even lists, and then perhaps use [List.zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353467.aspx) on those two lists to get them in to a list of key/value tuples.